# Add neighbouring values as a data field

Tags: arcgis-desktop

How can I add data based on neighbouring values?

If have a shapefile, dividing the country into different areas.
I have population data for each area. 
I would like to add new fields to my data, detailing the population of the neighbouring areas, for any area that shares a land border.

[image]

For example, in the case of area A, I would have the population of B and C in the adjacent fields (i.e. neighbour1 is B and neighbour2 is 3).

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this I would run the [Polygon Neighbors](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/tools/analysis-toolbox/polygon-neighbors.htm) tool which:

> Creates a table with statistics based on polygon contiguity (overlaps,
>   coincident edges, or nodes).

and then use an `arcpy.da.SearchCursor()` to read the table output by Polygon Neighbors and `arcpy.da.UpdateCursor()` to update the original feature class.